# Missing release management tasks in TFS 2015 on premise

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, ms-release-management

It appears a fair number of release management deployment tasks and templates are not in TFS 2015 on premise right now, and I'm trying to figure out if this is by design or if my installation has problems. For instance, I do not have a sql deployment task available to me. I haven't been able to find confirmation one way or the other, so does the on premise version just not have these tasks?

Comment: A bunch of these tasks (e.g., SQL server deployment) are available from the Visual Studio marketplace as extensions. You can usually install those extensions into the latest update of TFS server. Many of these do not work in the 2015 RTM version of TFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by designed. It seems you are using some **Extensions**. You can find this in available extensions on the right top of the web portal.
[image]

Then you can find those tasks in below page and just need manually install the tasks.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

be aware that VSTS development is always some months ahead of on-premise TFS. Especially release management is quite new and many enhancments and tasks will probably find it's way to TFS. Either directly, as extension or you can create custom tasks by yourself.
As seen here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/1674 it's a very young step and all you need to get it work on your local TFS is on github:
   https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/SqlServerDacpacDeployment

Answer (score 0):

DacPac deployments are part of the extention "IIS Web App Deployment Using WinRM"

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-rm.iiswebapp

Download and install it on your TFS server. You need to have Windows Remote Management enabled on your database servers for it to work.

I found this web site useful in getting it setup on the database server

http://www.hurryupandwait.io/blog/understanding-and-troubleshooting-winrm-connection-and-authentication-a-thrill-seekers-guide-to-adventure